# how to send file from specified path in response from local storage using node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, fs

I Have path tmp\daily_gasoline_report\9. where 9 is uniqe-id which will be different every time I want to send image from that folder in response. how can I send that file in response ??

I have tried with fs

```
    if (!req.body.path) {
        logger.warn(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
        return res.status(500).send(error.MANDATORY_FIELDS)
    }
    
    let directory_name = req.body.path;
    
    let filenames = fs.readdirSync(directory_name);

    console.log("\nFilenames in directory:"); 
    filenames.forEach((file) => { 
        console.log("File:", file); 
    }); 

    let result = error.OK
    result.data = filenames

    logger.info(result);
    return res.status(200).send(result)
```

I get only files name not files but now I have files name which comes in Url with path and file name from front end so, how can I send file from path in response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Answer

this worked for me to get single image from folder

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const url = require('url')

    let query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    let pic = query.image;
    let id = query.id

    let directory_name = "tmp/daily_gasoline_report/" + id + "/" + pic

    let filename = fs.existsSync(directory_name);

    if (filename) {

        //read the image using fs and send the image content back in the response
        fs.readFile(directory_name, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' })
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end(content);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let directory_name = req.body.path;

let filenames = fs.readdirSync(directory_name);

let resultantArr = [];

console.log("\nFilenames in directory:"); 
filenames.forEach((file) => { 
    console.log("File:", file); 

    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        var data = fr.result;
        var array = new Int8Array(data);
        resultantArr.push(JSON.stringify(array, null, '  '));
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}); 

let result = error.OK
result.data = resultantArr;

logger.info(result);
return res.status(200).send(result)
```

Comment: is it possible to get image from it's name

Comment: @Arya Yes, you would need an image path to read the image file.

Comment: i have tried as you said but got error ` TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined`

Answer (score 1):

@Arya Here is the code-snippet to deal with image file:

```
let fr = new FileReader();
fr.onloadend = function(event) {
    let base64Data = fr.result;
    let arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(base64Data);
    let blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: file.type } );
    resultantArr.push(blob);
}
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

And later on to read the blob values of an array and create image url out of it, you can do this:

```
let urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || {}.createObjectURL;
let imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
```

Comment: tmp\daily_gasoline_report\9\images-1600680185353.jpeg I want to access this images-1600680185353.jpeg from this req.params.path and send it in res[ponce

Comment: I am taking this images from local storage

Comment: I don't know what you wrote and why is it failing, unless you share the code. Please share the code, you can share the GitHub link as well.

Comment: i am updating question

Comment: Do not change the primary question, as that will lead to confusion for people who visit this page looking for a similar solution. Please share the GitHub URL

Comment: @Arya Changing the primary question completely is not recommended here. Please update it back to the primary question. And most importantly the code snippet will not help debug the issue you are trying to explain as I already shared the larger business logic around the use case showcasing the example. It is better if you share the Github URL of your failing code. I can help you debug with a specific issue.

Comment: i got the file names from first api now in second one i am trying to get the image from data which i got from first one

Answer (score 0):

you will need to zip all files in the path and send zip folder, you cannot send multiple files.

*Also cross check your requirements, if file size goes to big number your application will crash*